# Linear operator between normed spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

How could I proof the following statement?

Let X and Y be normed spaces and $T \in L(X,Y)$. If X is complete and T is 1-1, show that R(T) is complete iff $T^{-1}$ is continuous.

I have honestly no idea of how to do this. Maybe you could help me.

Answer (score 1):

If $R(T)$ is complete, the Bounded Inverse Theorem immediately gives the desired result.

Conversely, assume $T^{-1}$ is continuous. This means $R(T)$ is closed in $Y$. Now consider a Cauchy sequence $(y_n)\subset R(T)$. As $T^{-1}$ is continuous it follows that $(T^{-1}y_n)$ is Cauchy, but $X$ is complete, so $(T^{-1}y_n)$ converges to some $x\in X$. As $T$ is continuous it follows that $y_n$ converges to $Tx\in Y$, but $R(T)$ is closed, meaning that $Tx\in R(T).$ As $(y_n)$ was arbitrary $R(T)$ is complete.